# IE8 jQuery submit not working for forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have a form with a structure as such:

```
<form id="myForm">
  <div>
    <input .....>
    <input ......>
  </div>

  <div>
   <input ....>
   <input ....>
  </div>

  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I need to do an confirm box when the form is submitted so i did this:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if(confirm('something here')){
   $('myForm').submit();
  }
});
```

As we all know, IE8 does not like divs in form and clearly the html is a little broken. This results in my jquery being broken!

How can I work around this?

Comment: In what way does IE8 not like DIVs in FORMs? In what way is the HTML broken? What you posted looks ok. What does "this results in my jquery being broken" mean?

Comment: Also, if you have problems with jQuery use basic JavaScript/DOM. Attaching a confirmation dialog to a form is trivial without jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the `submit` event handler, if the confirmation is negative then you have to prevent the default action, it can be done via

It should be

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e){
  if(!confirm('something here')){
   e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if(confirm('something here')){
   this.submit();
  }
});
```

Comment: with in the jquery context ..`this` must be `$(this)` ..correct me if im wrong

Comment: @ubercooluk you want to trigger the javascript handler here, not the jquery's one, so it is `this.submit()` not `$(this).submit()`. BTW, firing jquery handler using `$(this)` would just recall the same handler again and again making infinite loop if confirm result is `true`. So ya, you are wrong :)

Comment: @ubercooluk you are welcome! This is classicly used when you want to wait for to submit form in result of an ajax request done inside the submit handler.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply use javascript, No need for doing extra effort on this

```
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="return confirm('Something Here');">
```

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have access to the html because it is automatically generated.